# Error while trying to insert into a collection from an already existing collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.6.6

In my database, I have two collections. One is empty, and one with 3000 documents. I would like to skip the first 2000 documents and only insert the last 1000 document from this collection into another one.

The collection containing 3000 documents is called `all_events` and the empty collection is `dates`

I used the command:

```
db.dates.insert(db.all_events.find().skip(2000))
```

But I got the error:

```
can't save a DBQuery object at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:143
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` returns a `DbCursor` object. `insert` accept `DbObject` or a list of `dbObject` as it's first parameter.

use something like:

```
db.full_set.find(...).forEach(function(e){
   db.copy.insert(e);
});
```